# jquery dialog pause a script like alert()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have next javascript code:

```
function getLetterOfResponsibilityNote(dialogNoteLink, visitCountryName) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/Admin/Applications/GetLetterOfResponsibilityNote/?selectedCountryName=" + visitCountryName,
            cache: false,
            success: function(data) {
                if (data != "") {
                    dialogNoteLink.dialog();
                    dialogNoteLink.attr("title", "Letter Of Responsibility Note for " + visitCountryName);
                    dialogNoteLink.html("<p>" + data + "</p>");
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

I want to call it, for example, 5 times and get data from server, then I will display it in dialog. But I get one Jquery UI Dialog with message. Problem is that script doesn't pause while dialog is open.

If I write instead of it:

```
dialogNoteLink.dialog();
dialogNoteLink.attr("title", "Letter Of Responsibility Note for " + visitCountryName);
dialogNoteLink.html("<p>" + data + "</p>");
```

with alert() - it works fine!

How I can resolve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is how JavaScript alert works. If you want to make the calls wait for the dialog to close, then you will have to make the subsequent calls in a callback after the dialog is closed. You should do something like this -

```
var arrayofNotesAndCountryNames = [{
 "dialogNoteLink" : link1,
 "visitCountryName" : "country1"
},{
 "dialogNoteLink" : link2,
 "visitCountryName" : "country2"
},{
 "dialogNoteLink" : link3,
 "visitCountryName" : "country3"
}];    
var currentIndex = 0;

function getLetterOfResponsibilityNote() {
var dialogNoteLink = arrayofNotesAndCountryNames[currentIndex].dialogNoteLink;
var visitCountryName = arrayofNotesAndCountryNames[currentIndex].visitCountryName;
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "/Admin/Applications/GetLetterOfResponsibilityNote/?selectedCountryName=" + visitCountryName,
                cache: false,
                success: function(data) {
                    if (data != "") {
                        dialogNoteLink.dialog({close : function(){ 
                             currentIndex++;
                             if (currentIndex < arrayofNotesAndCountryNames.length){
                                  getLetterOfResponsibilityNote();
                             }

                        }

});
                        dialogNoteLink.attr("title", "Letter Of Responsibility Note for " + visitCountryName);
                        dialogNoteLink.html("<p>" + data + "</p>");
                    }
                }
            });
        }

getLetterOfResponsibilityNote();
```

Answer (score 0):

The dialog should be shown from the callback of the query to the server.

There are no blocking function or dialogs on JQuery.